# finding topic log size to calculate consumer lag via __consumer_offset topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I've been looking into how to calculate consumer lag in Kafka and was wondering how one could calculate it using the `__consumer_offset` messages. `__consumer_offset` shows what the offsets are for each topic and partition and group, but how can you get the topic size in order to calculate the lag?

What I'm trying to do is store this data into Elasticsearch for analysis. I can pull the `__consumer_offset` data using logtash (as well as jmx data on teh brokers) but would now need to get the topic size to calculate the lag.

Comment: By 'the topic size', do you mean the `__consumer_offset` topic?

Comment: For any topic...

Comment: There is no out-of-box tool to get the total log size.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've come up with - and it's a bit of a scary hack - is this:
a) get and save the current position for each partition for your topic/group
b) do a seekToEnd - this re-positions all partitions 1 past the last record
c) re-query these positions, which equal the number of items for that partition
d) use the positions in (a) to do a seek(partition, position) to set each partition back to its original location

Scary since you are changing/resetting the original positions.